# change the frontend of checkout page

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to change the frontend of checkout page like picture below, i can find the phtml at onepage.phtml for checkout page, but i can't change the frontend because it's all script. How can i change the frontend then? for example, if i want to remove the shipping method at checkout page?

[image: checkout page]

Comment: It's better to take a look at: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html

Comment: yes i already take a loot at that link, but can i skip or remove the shipping method?

Comment: I think when working with Magento checkout, you need to be familiar with Js.